# Frozen columns not aligned with scrollable columns

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces

Basically, I've two columns.

> left --> Frozen columns
>
> right --> Scrollable columns

The code produces the image where the Frozen rows are not aligned with Scrollable rows. The rows of the scrollable columns changes it size based on the inputs fed, so applying CSS tricks doesn't work here. I couldn't find anything with regards to Primefaces to get this fixed.

So the only option left was to apply **jQuery code** to get this fixed. 
But somehow, the code is not producing expected results. Could someone help me to get this fixed?

For now, the code prints the following image:

[image]

**xhtml.page**

```
<ui:define name="content">
      <h:form id="identityForm">
        <div>
          <p:panel>

            <!--ui repeat-->
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="padding-right-5,max_width_944" styleClass="margin_bottom_30">
              <h:column>
                <p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty identityForm.halex}">

                  <table class="margin_top_27">
                    <tr>
                      <th class="height_26"></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="header ui-state-default">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['hal.col.name']}" />
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{identityForm.halex}" var="halex}" varStatus="halLine">
                      <tr class="#{itemLine.odd ? 'oddRow' : 'evenRow'}">
                        <td class="row-content height_54" style="width: 57px;">
                          <h:outputText value="#{halex.shortCode}" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </ui:repeat>
                  </table>

                </p:outputPanel>
              </h:column>

              <h:column>
                <div class="max_width_944 overflow-x">
                  <table id="free_columns">
                    <ui:repeat value="#{halexBean.selectedHalexItem}" var="hal">
                      <tr>
                        <th class="header ui-state-default">
                          <h:outputText value="#{msgs['hal.col.customer']}" />
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </ui:repeat>

                    <ui:repeat value="#{halexBean.selectedType}" var="lam" varStatus="status">
                      <tr class="#{status.odd?'oddRow':'evenRow'}">
                        <td class="row-content">
                          <h:outputText value="#{partType.name}"></h:outputText>   
                        </td>
                        <td class="row-content" style="min-width:150px;">
                          <h:outputText value="#{partType.age}"></h:outputText>
                        </td>
                        <td class="row-content">
                          <h:outputText value="#{partType.address}" />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </ui:repeat>

                  </table>
                </div>
              </h:column>

            </h:panelGrid>
          </p:panel>
        </div>
      </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

**css.page**

```
 .padding-right-5 {
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .max_width_944 {
        max-width: 944px;
    }

    margin_top_27 {
        margin-top: 27px;
    }

    .row-content {
        min-width: 100px;
        min-height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 57px;
    }
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {                          

                 $("#free_columns tr").each(function (index, element) {

                    //get row height from freeColumnTable and the corresponding row in table frozenColumns
                    var rowOneHeight = $(this).height();
                    var rowTwo = $(".row-content tr:eq(" + index + ")");

                    //if no matching row was found in table two, stop loop
                    if (!rowTwo.length) return false;
                    var rowTwoHeight = rowTwo.height();

                    //compare row heights, and set the least high row to the height of the highest one
                    if (rowOneHeight > rowTwoHeight) {
                        //set rowTwoHeight to rowOneHeight
                       rowTwo.height(rowOneHeight);
                    } else {
                             $(this).height(rowTwoHeight);
                           }
               });
           });
</script>
```

Comment: As a very crude workaround you could add the input to the fixed table too, and then hide the column. This should cause the height between the two to match.

Comment: @SchoolBoy  and how could that be done?

Comment: No, a very crude workaround, like I mentioned. I am not sure what the standard approach would be for something like this. To me though, if the table is not joined with the other one, I see no point in making their rows the same height as they are different tables and won't scroll together so won't be aligned on scroll anyway.

Comment: Its how the business wants to look their page like. So got to make it happen, no matter how.

Comment: What PF version? Checked the release notes? Checked the issuelist? Difficult issue to fix yourself.

Comment: Primefaces version is 3.4. I understand its a difficult task, but trying to find out a workaround, if possible.

Comment: But now I see it, this question is totally not PrimeFaces related...

Comment: Absolutely @Kukeltje. Looks like some jQuery hack might do the trick. I doubt whether Primefaces has a fix for this.

Comment: A fix for **your code**? No, but they had the same problem in their datatable and recently fixed it if I remember correctly (check their issuelist/releasenotes)